# How to order a list by type?

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm, list, extension-methods

Imagine that you have a list called `List<Foo>`.

`Foo` is an abstract class, so this can be `FooA`, `FooB`, `FooC` or `FooD`. And I'd like to have an extension for `List<T>` where you can order this elements by type but sequently.

For example, if I have 9 elements in it.

```
FooA, FooA, FooB, FooD, FooC, FooC, FooA, FooB, FooA
```

Order by type sequently will be.

```
FooA, FooB, FooC, FooD, FooA, FooB, FooC, FooA, FooA
```

I'm trying that the function can be ordered at the order you specify, at this case, IE, it was:

```
new[] { typeof(FooA), typeof(FooB), typeof(FooC), typeof(FooD) }
```

I was trying to create this extension, but I don't get anything. Can you help a little bit? I'm guessing that I can accomplish it with LINQ.

Comment: what happens if there is no FooC in the list or there is FooA, FooB, FooC, FooC, FooC, FooD, how do you sort that? i would recommend you adapting selection sort for your purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can group the items by type, sort the groups by type and interleave the groups:

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(x => x.GetType())
                  .OrderBy(g => orderedTypes.IndexOf(g.Key))
                  .ToList();

var result = groups.First().Interleave(groups.Skip(1).ToArray());
```

using the [Interleave method from EvenMoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/r/azizatif-morelinq-evenmore/source/browse/MoreLinq/Interleave.cs).

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.GetType());
}
```

*Output:*

```
FooA
FooB
FooC
FooD
FooA
FooB
FooC
FooA
FooA
```

Answer (score 1):

Group on the type, then loop through the items to add one set each time. Something like:

```
var groups =
  collection.GroupBy(x => x.GetType())
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());

List<Foo> result = new List<Foo>();
int max = groups.Values.Max(n => n.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
  foreach (Type  t in sortArray) {
    if (groups[t].Count > i) {
      result.Add(groups[t][i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @L.B: The array of `Type` objects that specifies the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

`list` is a collection of elements to be sorted.
`pattern` is a collection of elements in specific order.
`result` is a collection of elements from `list` ordered according to the `pattern`.

```
var list = new List<Foo> { new FooA(), new FooB(), new FooC(), new FooA(), new FooC(), new FooA(), new FooD() };
var pattern = new Foo[] { new FooB(), new FooC(), new FooD(), new FooA() };

var result = list.OrderBy(p => p, new MyFooComparer(pattern));
```

There is a class `MyFooComparer` that implements interface `IComparer<>`.
 Comparison is based on the position of each `Foo` in `pattern` collection. `pattern` elements **must not be duplicated** and they must contain all types of `Foo` (at least those used in `list`).
 I used `Dictionary<>` to store the pattern order because it has O(1) complexity.

```
public class MyFooComparer : IComparer<Foo>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, int> _pattern;
    public MyFooComparer(IEnumerable<Foo> pattern)
    {
        _pattern = new Dictionary<Type, int>();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var foo in pattern)
        {
            _pattern.Add(foo.GetType(), i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    public int Compare(Foo x, Foo y)
    {
        var xVal = _pattern[x.GetType()];
        var yVal = _pattern[y.GetType()];
        return xVal.CompareTo(yVal);
    }
}
```

After calling:

```
        foreach (var foo in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType().Name);
        }
```

According to the `pattern`, you will get:

```
FooB
FooC
FooC
FooD
FooA
FooA
FooA
```

**EDIT:**

Extension for `List<Foo>`:

```
static class MyExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<Foo> OrderByFoo<T>(this List<Foo> list, IEnumerable<Foo> patern)
    {
        return list.OrderBy(p => p, new MyFooComparer(patern));
    }
}
```